# Project setup problem in Intellij's react+kotlin

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

Actually from 2-3 days, I am trying my hands on react with kotlin. But there is some error in setup of the project.

I am just following this documentation : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-get-started.html#update-the-application.

But whenever I run the project it shows the following error:[Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 420 ms

> Task :kotlinNodeJsSetup SKIPPED
> Task :packageJson UP-TO-DATE
> Task :rootPackageJson
> Task :kotlinNpmInstall FAILED
> 3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':kotlinNpmInstall'.

> Cannot find webpack@4.44.1 in yarn.lock
> ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsdqT.jpg)

And I have tried almost everything. I have checked for all files. Checked the NPM & YARN installation , everything. I am using react and I never faced a problem in it. Please help !!